# What's wrong with "I spent much money"?

Tags: grammar

> I spent much money.

I know it's common to say "I spent a lot of money.", but why is the above sentence wrong?

Comment: There isn't much wrong with that sentence. Much depends on how things sound to our ears, and that short sentence doesn't sound very native-like today. The question form: "How much money did you spend?" is perfectly grammatical, as is the negative reply: "Not much" and its affirmative: "Too much!". Generally speaking, use *much* in questions and in negative sentences when the noun being modified is UNCOUNTABLE.  And use *many* when the noun is COUNTABLE as in "How many dogs were in the park?" Answers: "There weren't many" [neg] and " Too many, to count" [pos]

Comment: @Mari-Lou A You could make that into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's not wrong.  I will construct a situation in which I might use it:

> I visited New York City.  I heard loud car horns.  I climbed tall buildings.  I ate great food.  I walked great distances.  I spent much money.  I came home poorer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that *much* is not a regular adjective.  It's modern classification is as a [**determiner and pronoun** or an **adverb**](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&q=define%20much). None of the below sound correct, because the sentences try to get it to behave like an adjective:

1. There were much dogs in the park.
2. Much doorknobs were lost.
3. He had much subordinates.

Personally, I don't think the sentence, "I spent much money." sounds that bad, nor does its negation, "I did not spend much money.". That said, it does sound better to my ears to replace "much" with "a lot of".

Comment: Your examples all sound wrong because they're countable nouns. Replace them with non-countable nouns, and they sound fine, while *many* sounds wrong. For example: *"There was many discontent among the poor."* *"Many knowledge was lost."* "*He had many fun.*"